# A generalized Dirac operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, 4-manifolds, spin-geometry, dirac-operator

Let $(M^4,g)$ be a closed four-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $J$ be an almost complex structure on $M$. Then for normal coordinate $e_1,\dots e_4$ at a point $m,$ and for a section $\alpha$ of a $\mathrm{Spin}^\mathrm{c}$ bundle $V$ on $M$, one can define the operator:
\begin{equation*}
D_J(\alpha)=\sum_i J(e_i)\cdot \nabla_i\alpha 
\end{equation*}

This can be seen as:
\begin{equation*}
\Gamma(V)\xrightarrow{\nabla}\Omega^1(M)\otimes\Gamma(V)\xrightarrow{J}\Omega^1(M)\otimes\Gamma(V)\xrightarrow{\text{Cliff. mult.}}\Gamma(V)
\end{equation*}

Does this operator appear in the literature? If $D$ denotes the usual Dirac operator and $D\alpha$ vanishes, can we say something about $D_J\alpha?$

**Comment:** At a first glance this reminded me about the twisted differential, one defines in Kähler geometry:
\begin{equation*}
d^c:=\sum_i Je_i\wedge \nabla_i
\end{equation*}
I am not sure if this helps in any way though.